# accessing folder

Tags: linux, root, ubuntu-8.10

I tried to access my folder but warning say you are not root and  and permission area 
doesnot clearly open that is I couldnot access its feature to change its permission
and sudo is not accessible 
    Moreover, sudo nautilus is not useable 
    warning is e1630862 is not in the sudoers file.
   how can I access

Comment: Are you logged in with the same user account that was created when the system was installed?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to find your root password, login as root and then do your thing.

Comment: AFAIK, Ubuntu does not use a root password -- everything is done through sudo or the like.

Comment: I see. Interesting. So he'll need to find/use an account that has sudo privilege and then do his thing.

Comment: how can I find my user password, I didn ot note it at any paper.Are there any method loggin in then recreate password